# How can we insert Date into oracle table using TO_DATE injava?

Tags: java, oracle10g, netbeans-7

I'm try to execute this function but I'm getting an exception.Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

```
public static void insertTransaction(String St_Id,String Bk_Id,String issuedate,String returndate)//throws Exception
    {
        getConnection();
        try{
         select.executeUpdate("insert into TRANSACTION values('"+St_Id+"','"+Bk_Id+"',to_date('"+issuedate+"','DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('"+returndate+"','DD-MON-YYYY')");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("In Excpetion of insert");
        }
    }
```

Comment: paste your exception here

Comment: You could probably solve you problem by making use of `PreparedStatement`s and simply applying a `Date` object to specific parameter

Comment: Also, paste `issuedate ` and `returndate` value

Comment: Did you checked the format of issuedate and returndate

Comment: you should be using the date format "10-10-2017". If not, it will throw an exception. The values might be null or different format.